# How to work with group topics by using Telethon lib?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

There is no information about a group topics. I tryd find any information on the official site.
Function client.iter_dialogs() and client.get_dialogs() dont consider topics. They retourn only list of opened conversation.

When I triyd send message to group with a topic using function client.send_message() there was arrors when topic "General" was closed. Whet it was open there wasnt any arrors, and a messege was sent it the General topic of a group. I understood that function send_message() can send massage to group with topics. So, I want have posability chouse a topic and write there. And get list of topics where user already wrote any messages, from opened group dialogs.

I sent a few massages by Telegram and got its log. Found the part where it sendes the message. I didn't understand where it sends topic ID.
TL_messages_sendMessage didn't get any parameter. And "send message" aither.

Log below:

Dialog ID: 1***098800
Topic ID: 258

01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: notify item inserted 0
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: update messageRead currentMaxId = 334 dialogId = -1***098800

01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: send message user_id = 0 chat_id = 0 channel_id = 1***098800 access_hash = 6691323840089318717 notify = true silent = false
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: send request org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_messages_sendMessage@80b5824 with token = 616
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator enable notifications
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator disable notifications

01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: update topic -1***098800 258 0 0
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: java received org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_updates@875347f error = null
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: processNewChannelDifferenceParams pts = 348 pts_count = 1 channeldId = 1***098800
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: APPLY CHANNEL PTS
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: process update TLRPC$TL_updateMessageID
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: send request org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_messages_getMessagesReactions@9203c4c with token = 617
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: update messageRead currentMaxId = 334 dialogId = -1***098800

01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: update topic -1***098800 258 0 0
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: java received org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_updates@3e10495 error = null
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator enable notifications
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator enable notifications
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator disable notifications

01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: send request org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_messages_setTyping@73387d6 with token = 618
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: java received org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_boolTrue@44ff5b0 error = null
01_07_2023_16_28_09 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator enable notifications

01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: received new messages 1 in dialog -1***098800

01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: notify item inserted 0
01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: update messageRead currentMaxId = 334 dialogId = -1***098800

01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: send message user_id = 0 chat_id = 0 channel_id = 1***098800 access_hash = 6691323840089318717 notify = true silent = false
01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: send request org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC$TL_messages_sendMessage@e553f6b with token = 619
01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator enable notifications
01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: chatItemAnimator disable notifications
01_07_2023_16_28_10 D/tmessages: update topic -1***098800 258 0 0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved first part of task. Full API has functions.channels.GetForumTopicsRequest function. So now I can get list of group topics. Also I can get all attributes ot topics. Now I whant send message to the topic. But I dont know howe. send_message() need chanel_ID. But I have only chenel_ID of group  and topi_ID of topic. I can generete invite link to topic like: inviteLink='https://t.me/'+dialog.entity.username+"/"+str(topic.id).
But when I tryed  send_message(inviteLink, "hi") there were arror "Cannot find any entity corresponding to "https://t.me/****/1""

Comment: Now I am forced to use debug mode. It's new and interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper topic support in the `TelegramClient` for Telethon v1, but you can always [use raw API](https://tl.telethon.dev/) and [search for topic](https://tl.telethon.dev?q=topic) to learn what is possible.

How to take it from there is outside my knowledge though. But you can always look into how official clients are doing it (by e.g. [enabling debug mode](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/25665#issuecomment-1370685922), the linked issue doesn't matter, only the procedure to enable it; then checking the requests it makes).

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday I solved the part of the task. I found all I need in https://tl.telethon.dev/. But now I have second one part. I dont know how I can sand message directly into the topic. https://tl.telethon.dev/ has no information.

Comment: Telegram's naming is obscure but I believe it's the `top_msg_id` from [`sendMessage`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/send_message.html).

Comment: So did I. Unfortunatly its belong to replay mesage procedures only. https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage
"top_msg_id - This field must contain the topic ID only when replying to messages in forum topics different from the "General" topic (i.e. reply_to_msg_id is set and reply_to_msg_id != topicID and topicID != 1).
If the replied-to message is deleted before the method finishes execution, the value in this field will be used to send the message to the correct topic, instead of the "General" topic."